# Delay logic of an optical sensor

Tags: sensor, delay, time, optical

I have a simple optical sensor that has 3 pins: Power (5V), Signal (5V when not triggered), and Ground. When the sensor is triggered, the signal goes to 0 V.

I need to constantly delay the signal by a small amount of time. I am not exactly sure how much time to delay, maybe 300 ms? Will have to experiment (a variable knob to set delay time would be great!).

Note: The sensor will be triggered quite a lot.

Can this be done with simple components/IC, or do I need an Arduino?

Edit: this is an optical sensor in a coin hopper for giving change from $1 and $5 bills. Right now the sensor is working properly, but the controller turns off the motor as soon as the sensor triggers and the last coin doesn't quite come out of the hopper. I am hoping if I can delay the signal a wee bit the coin will clear before the motor turns off.

Comment: You can buy lab delay boxes that let you dial in exact delays on logic signals. They're very useful for optical applications, we used them all the time for lidar.

Answer (score 1):

This would be very difficult to implement with logic gates as you would need a long delay and most components have short delays in the us to ns range. Therefore a microprocessor would be best with a software timer

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with one logic gate, a non-inverting buffer.  However, it will perform much better with two logic gates, either Schmitt Trigger inverters (such as the CD40106) or Schmitt Trigger NAND gates (such as the CD4093).

The first gate is a buffer, so the time delay network has a consistent driving point.  The timing network is a series resistor and a shunt capacitor to GND.  This will delay both the positive-going and negative-going edges of the sensor signal.  For better adjustability, the series resistor can be a combination of two resistors - one fixed and one variable.  The fixed resistor sets the minimum delay time (when the variable resistor is at 0 ohms).  The sum of the two resistors sets the maximum delay time.

Please update your question with information about what the output signal is used for, what type of device or circuit it drives, etc.  This might affect the logic gates used.  Also, please give the min and max delay periods.

Here is a circuit from last year on another forum.  It shows the basic concept.  For your application, R1, R2, and C1 all would have larger values.  As R2 is turned to the right, the delay period increases.

[image]